# Xcode MacOS where to store binary file that's needed

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, resources, store

I've got an executable file that is written in C which outputs some information I need in my Cocoa App. My question is where do I store this executable file in my project? And what is going to be the path where it is gonna be stored when I release the App?

I've read about the Application Support folder. Printing this out

```
print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first)
```

gets me

```
Optional(file:///Users/cemal/Library/Containers/noorganization.ProjectName/Data/Library/Application%20Support/)
```

Is this where my binary file will be stored? If yes, where do I have to store it now at build time, so it gets stored in the Application Support folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll likely want store the additional binary within the `.app` bundle, in the `MacOS` directory — Storing it elsewhere could create issues, especially if it's a location that might be inaccessable.

**.app/Contents/MacOS**

> Typically, this directory contains only one binary file with your
>   application’s main entry point and statically linked code. However,
>   you may put other standalone executables (such as command-line tools)
>   in this directory as well.

↳ [Bundle Programming Guide : Bundle Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW3)

Comment: Thx! I just copied the file into my project folder and looked if it got stored somewhere in the .app bundle and it did. It got stored in the Resources folder instead of MacOS. But I think that's no problem if I leave it there as long as I know where it is at runtime

Comment: You can specify where to put the additional binary in the `Build Phases` > `+` > `New Copy Files Phase` > then add the binary and select `Executables` path as the destination. In Swift you can get the path via (`print(Bundle.main.executablePath!` or `print(Bundle.main.executableURL!`).